# Функция через рекурсию С++

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Функция выводит значение n-ого члена последовательности, нужно написать такую же функцию, только с рекурсией. Понятия не имею как это сделать. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
int Sequence(int size, int n)

int* array = new int[size];
array[0] = 0;
array[1] = 2;
array[2] = 5;
for (int i = 3; i < size; i++)

    array[i] = array[i - 1] - array[i - 2] + array[i - 3];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)

    cout << "[" << i + 1 << "]= " << array[i] << endl;

return array[n-1];
```

Comment: И все же было бы не плохо показать пример того как вы пытались это сделать

Comment: Для начала просто вынесите операцию получения нового члена в отдельную функцию, а после этого сделайте эту функцию рекурсивной, для этого вам понадобится лишь добавить еще один аргумент  - счетчик. Все элементарно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекурсивные версии часто короткие и выразительные. Чтобы "иметь понятие", нужно почитать и потренироваться

```
int Foo(int n) {
   if (n<=3)
      return n*(n+1)/2-1;
   else
      return Foo(n-1)-Foo(n-2)+Foo(n-3)
}
```

Что касается массива, заполняемого функцией в вопросе: если аргументы могут быть великИ, или получать значения нужно много раз, то имеет смысл сохранять то, что уже вычислили. Этот приём называется "мемоизация". Пусть для простоты существует глобальный массив `A[]` размером `size`, заполненный нулями. Добавляем всего пару строчек, и получаем гораздо более эффективную функцию (первая имеет экспоненциальную сложность, т.к. вычисляет одни и те же значения много раз):

```
int Foo(int n) {
    if (A[n-1] <= 0)  { 
        if (n<=3) 
            A[n-1] =  n*(n+1)/2-1;
        else
            A[n-1] = Foo(n-1)-Foo(n-2)+Foo(n-3);
    }  
    return A[n-1];
}
```

Comment: Небольшая разница в том, что побочным эффектом итеративной функции ТС был заполненный массив

Comment: @avp Да, я обратил внимание, даже size задаётся, отличный от n, но непонятно, нужна ли здесь мемоизация, и на что именно направлена учебная задача.

Comment: @avp это побочный эффект не итеративной функции, а слабых навыков тс - этот массив с легкостью заменяется просто на 3 переменные с тем же результатом

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, опять же, если ТС просит написать *такую же, но через рекурсию*, то м.б. имеет смысл показать, что можно передавать массив в рекурсивные вызовы.

Comment: @avp а зачем? Всмысле этот массив задействован только внутри функции и никак снаружи. Если представить функцию как черную коробку, то последнее что в ней ожидаешь найти, это бесполезный кусок памяти, который не нужен от слова совсем

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, для меня очевидно, что неплохо было бы довести до ТС мысль об этом и показать, каким образом массив может оказаться доступным извне